# Is there a way to run R code (with packages from cran and github) in python?

Tags: python, r

I am working on a project where a github package in R needs to be used in Python. Hence I am looking for a package that can help to run and install r codes and packages(both cran and guthub) in python

Comment: rpy2 below as suggested by james would work. I think it's more suitable as a question if you have a concrete example, like for example i need to use library a,b,c on this r code and I need to run it from python etc..

Comment: there can be some problems though, depending on what you need to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the post here. It should tell you what you want to know.

https://sites.google.com/site/aslugsguidetopython/data-analysis/pandas/calling-r-from-python